# Winter bash hats not shown to other users?

Tags: support, winter-bash

Today I found a link to [winterba.sh](http://winterba.sh) on the top bar. Upon clicking the "I love hats" button, I was offered to wear the [L'chaim](http://winterba.sh/lchaim) hat. The hat shows up as an overlay on my profile picture. But when viewing my profile after logging off, the hat is no longer shown. So I assume one's hat is visible only to the same logged in user.

Methinks the hats are ugly anyway, but what's the use of wearing it if others can't see it?

Comment: If you think the hats are ugly, then you should click the "I hate hats" link.

Comment: I can see mine (and yours) when I'm in incognito mode—did you try refreshing? Something old might still be cached in your browser.

Comment: @0x7fffffff I love hats. But not the one I was given :-)

Comment: @waiwai933 I did try using incognito mode and refreshing.

Comment: If you don't like the hat you have, work on getting one you do like. There are a number to choose from.

Comment: Since this is a "core" feature of Winter Bash, retagging to use the general tag, and not for a specific year

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hats are ONLY visible on Stack Overflow to users who have chosen to opt-in to the promo. Whereas other sites are able to opt-in as a site, Stack Overflow's size and daily traffic made this a non-option.

To compensate: users who choose to "love hats" will see the *other* users who love hats wearing headgear. Otherwise, anonymous, drive-by, logged-out, and hat-hating users will see no hats anywhere.

Comment: Where is YOUR hat??? ;) Edit: oh, it's no hat but OK. :)

Comment: I accidentally clicked on the "i hate hats" button.  How do I get the hats back?

Comment: @daaxix Click the Winterbash link on the tap bar and click "I love hats" and you should be fine!