# Hats available for all Stack Overflow websites

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

1. Whether these hats will be visible on each and every profile picture of all the websites of the Stack Exchange Network?
2. Conditions will be applicable to all sister websites of Stack Overflow?
3. What if I got down vote on the question on which I got 1 up vote?

**UPDATED:**

I have 5 upvotes and even asked a question on meta and showing **`you earned 2 winterbash`**
but on winterbash it is showing **`You haven't earned this hat on any sites yet.`**

Comment: Are you logged in and clicked I love hats?

Comment: @AustinHenley done need to logout..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Some sites have opted out of hats. This decision was made by the moderators of that site (though, in most cases, the mods let the community decide).

The hat is displayed on the site wherever your avatar is, only to logged in users who have not opted out (in the case of SO, opted in) to hats.

The set of hats earned is different on each site. While http://winterba.sh/ ma list all hats earned, you can only use the hats earned on a particular site on that site.

2. Yep, the hat criteria is the same.
3. If [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159216/178438) is false (probably), then you get to keep the hat (if you got the downvote later). I'm not sure about getting an upvote after a downvote--I read "upvoted posts" as "score>0"

---

Finally, the other SE sites are *not* "sub websites" of StackOverflow. They are sites belonging to the [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/), just like SO. "Sister sites of SO" is OK, "subwebsites" makes me grinch-y. :P

Comment: Worth to mention only logged in users [who have chosen to opt-in to the promo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159140/152859) will see your hat. Anonymous visitors will see the gravatar as usual, without any hat.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Thanks, fixed :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's *only* true on Stack Overflow. On the other sites (who have opted in *as a site*) individuals must *opt-out* instead.

Comment: @Aarthi oh, thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

1. The hats are visible on just about every where your profile picture is shown (except chat)
2. I think you mean all sub websites of Stack Exchange? Yes, but each site has their own hats so you have to unlock them on each site, just like rep.
3. [You keep the hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159228/169404). From what I saw, you don't lose hats when the conditions are no longer true, just like badges.

Comment: it should be also on chat

Comment: @NullPointer I agree!