# Winter Bash Hats On profile pic are visible only to logged in users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash-2013

If I am logged in, I can see that on the user's profile page, the hat is visible. But if I open the profile URL of the same user after logging out, there is no hat on the gravatar. Shouldn’t it still be visible?

Comment: People can opt in and out of Winter Bash. So showing them only to those who are logged in makes a lot of sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winter bash hats not shown to other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159133/winter-bash-hats-not-shown-to-other-users)

Comment: @Azik While that's somewhat true, I'd leave this open because of slight differences between 2012 and 2013 (this year, it's more than only Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the case on those sites were you only get hats when you opt in, either by clicking "I love hats", or by simply wearing a hat. These sites are:

- Stack Overflow
- Tex
- Homebrew
- Quant
- Mechanics
- Bitcoin
- Linguistics
- Chinese
- Poker
- Mathematica
- Russian
- Open data
- Sound

For Stack Overflow, the reason is mainly performance; for the others it's because the sites didn't opt in to showing hats by default. Math Overflow is completely hatless.

Comment: Math nerds don't like hats. :/