# Some sites think I'm a hat hater

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I though the link to the Winterbash page was at the bottom so I misclicked on **I hate hats !**

> [image]

Of course, I love them so I rapidly clicked on **I love hats** and hoped that I didn't loose all this precious headgear. No one was hurt, all the hats were there waiting for me...

But on every other sites, I'm still seen as a hat hater.
Is this by design ? Do I have to state I'm a hat lover on every site because of that mistake I once made...

> [image]

Comment: feel the hate flow through you

Comment: @Servy I think he'd rather feel the hat...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you click "I like hats" on Meta, that'll put your setting back to the default, which means you see hats on all sites except for those listed [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211828/115866).

By the way, the easiest way to say "I like hats" is putting one on – unless you check "only on this site", the "Wear hat" button auto-opts you in.