# This hat doesn't belong to me

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013

I got this hat on Stack Overflow and put it on in my profile. Then, I disabled hats on my Stackoverflow account, but that hat is still showing on Meta.

It is also not in my list of hats.

> [image: hats]

Comment: It's probably mine. GIVE IT BACK TO ME. *NOW!*

Comment: @AmalMurali No!! already two down-voters claim it :)

Comment: Hit "I hate hats" on MSO and it should go away.

Comment: That's some pretty bad compression artifacts in that image (just saying)

Comment: @AmericanLuke because it's a JPG screenshot. Bad idea, I learned very early to save screenshot only as PNG. The JPG is good for pictures, not much more.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller no global "I hate hats"? If one is member in 112 sites, he'll have to click it on each and every one of them?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, just on one of the sites that are default-on, e.g. right here. It's the reverse case of http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212133/115866.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller but using a hat which I do not have.. I think is not a good design

Comment: Winter Bash thinks you own it because you earned it on Stack Overflow, even though you disabled hats on Stack Overflow. You should be able to wear different hats anyway. Just enjoy your extra hat for the next few weeks until they go away :)